My wife is a Belgian citizen and I am a Pakistani citizen living in Belgium. Can we visit Mexico without visas?
My wife is a Belgian citizen and I am a Pakistani citizen living in Belgium with my wife.  I have EU family status here. Can we travel to Mexico without a visa for 10 days?

Yes.
Visa nationals who are permanent residents of/hold a valid and current visa for any Schengen country may enter Mexico for up to 180 days.
You can check full entry documentation requirements by inputting your itinerary and travel document data into the IATA website.
